# Database interaction between HTML page and Sqlite on a WebServer?

Tags: android, .net, sqlite, webserver, android-sqlite

I need to create a HTML page with will interact with Sqlite database. This page and database will reside on an android device. This HTML page will be accessed by devices(PCs) connected to this android device locally. Since I have .NET background with no experience in Sqlite Or android etc, I am clueless as to what technology/language I will have to use. C# won't work I suppose.
Any suggestions? How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tools/libraries to achieve what you want:

- [**`NanoHTTPD` Server**](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd): A lightweight `HTTP` server for Android. You can read more about it on the Github project page. You can either use the *bare* server and add features like routing, etc. on top of it or use the [**`Nanolets`**](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd#nanolets) class provided by `NanoHTTPD`. There isn't much documentation around `Nanolets` but they are more-or-less like *servlets* for Android. To know more about them checkout this [test file](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/nanolets/src/test/java/org/nanohttpd/junit/router/AppNanolets.java).
- [**`Room Persistence library`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html): Room is a lightweight orm for SQLite developed by Google and is a part of the [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) library. It abstracts away lots of boilerplate code you would have to otherwise write when using SQLite on Android.
  Although, if you are just getting started on Android or are otherwise learning Android I would still recommend *bare* SQLite framework shipped with Android to know what is *actually going on under the hood*.

Using the above mentioned libraries, you can create a *server on your device* that can serve your requests. I would recommend that you develop a  *REST-like* API for your service and interact with the API from JavaScript  in the browser running on the PC.

You can use *any* JavaScript frameworks like Angular, React, Vue or even jQuery  to build a single page front-end application to your service, bundle the JavaScript in a single package (using something like webpack) and ship the resulting bundle alongwith your Android app (preferably inside the `/resources` or `/assets` directory). You can the *serve* the bundle from Android device whenever another device connects to it, and then use the API to handle business logic.

Comment: How do my HTML page interact with database? I can't access database using JQuery.

Comment: That's what the *Rest API* is for! You create your web app in (say) jQuery, bundle it up with the Android application, serve the javascript file when the browser makes the first request and then handle all subsequent communication via the Rest API, sort of like how you would develop a website with a Rest API backend

Comment: Please tell me if I have got this right....I will host HTML + javascript + sqlite file on android device, and create a .NET API service on my PC (which is connected to the android device on LAN). I can open HTML page on my PC click on html button, which in turn will make a ajax call to the service deployed on my PC , which will access sqlite database and send the data to HTML page.

Comment: No my friend! You are complicating the issue here... First of all there is no need for .NET/C# or anything, secondly, you will host your HTML+JS from your Android device that you will access using the PC  (you have to serve the file from Android using NanoHTTPD, much like Apache/Nginx) and then once the html+jsis on your PC you will make AJAX request to the Android device. You have to handle that AJAX request using (say) NanoHTTPD and then access the database, form your response and send it back to the browser

Comment: The thing is, I know .NET/C#. I can write code in C#. If I make AJAX request to NanoHTTPD then I will have to use some language other than C#  etc to access database.

Comment: Oops! then you are out-of-luck trying here! You *cannot embed* C# code in Java code and since your database is on Android, you have use Java (or Kotlin)... One way would be create your whole app from scratch in something like [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) that uses C# as it's language

Comment: I am not trying to create any app. There is already an app on android which is writing to this database. I was just wondering if it's possible to access this database from windows PC using LINQ or something?